# Ionic, AngularJs: Directive attribute $watch stops working after view is rendered

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ionic-framework

I want to create an attribute directive for ionItem and I want it to watch its own value:

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="item in items" my-dir="{{data.watchedValue}}">….</ion-item>
```

I have an issue with creating correct watch statement in the directive. The watch is executed only once during initial view rendering. After that it is not invoked when `data.watchedValue` is changed.

Specific of the directive is that it is child of `ionItem` directive.

I have tried multiple approaches (see comments in my-dir source), but none of them works.

Directive:

```
.directive('myDir', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require:  '^ionItem',
    link: function(scope, element, attr, itemCtrl) {
      console.log('my-dir initial value: ' + attr.myDir);

      if (angular.isDefined(attr.myDir)) {
        // scope.$watch("(" + attr.myDir + " === \"true\")", function(value) {
        // scope.$watch('!!(' + attr.myDir + ')', function(value) {
        scope.$watch(attr.myDir, function(value) {
          console.log('my-dir watch new value:  ' + value);
        });
      }

    } // link
  }; // return
}) // directive
```

Simplified directive usage:

```
<button class="button" ng-click="data.watchedValue = !data.watchedValue">
  Change Value
</button>

<ion-content>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item ng-repeat="item in items" my-dir="{{data.watchedValue}}">
      Item {{ item.id }}. Watched property: {{ data.watchedValue }}
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

[Code Pen](http://codepen.io/MichalFoksa/pen/EgjQLB?editors=1010#0) with full example. Press `Change Value` button to … change  value.

Watch the console for any logs after initial display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be just passing scope variable name to directive `attribute`

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="item in items" my-dir="data.watchedValue">
  Item {{ item.id }}. Watched property: {{ data.watchedValue }}
</ion-item>
```

**OR**

you could use `attrs.$observe` instead of `$scope.$watch`, which will basically keep an watch on `{{}}` interpolated value specified on attribute.

> If `data.watchedValue` has object then I'd highly recommend to go for
>   1st approach.

Comment: That was it! The first approach. `my-dir="data.watchedValue"` and NOT `my-dir="{{data.watchedValue}}"`. Thank you!